# delete custom post type using a submit form

Tags: custom-post-types, posts

here i'm trying on submitting to delete the post in process.. i've tried without the hidden input aswell as doing the if isset on the redirecting page when form's submit. all 3 ways failed.

```
if(isset($_POST['postType'])
       && isset($_POST['idValue']))
    {

        $post_type = $_POST['postType'];
        $id_post = $_POST['idValue'];               

        $postInfo = array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
            'ID' => $id_post
        );

        wp_delete_post($postInfo, true);

    }

    if(isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] == "Supprimer")
    {

        ?>

            <div id="overlay">
                <div id="SupprimerAnnonce">

                    <form method="post" action="<?php echo add_query_arg( 'action', 'Deleted', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']); ?>">
                        <p>&Ecirc;tes-vous s&ucirc;r de vouloir supprimer</p>
                        <p><b><?php the_field('titre') ?></b></p>
                        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Continuer"/>
                        <?php 

                            $post_type = get_post_type( get_the_ID() );
                            $id_post = get_the_ID();

                        ?>

                            <input type="hidden" name="idValue" value="<?php echo $id_post; ?>" readonly />
                            <input type="hidden" name="postType" value="<?php echo $post_type; ?>" readonly />

                    </form>
                </div>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('overlay').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'" title="Fermer">Fermer</a>
            </div>
            <div id="fade"></div>

        <?php

    }
```

Any tips ?

Thx

Comment: Debug your outcomes. Your conditions might not be getting met. Put some else statements on there and output that stuff to a log file or something.

Comment: Here is what i tried. instead of having multiple condition on one page, if the user click continue on deleting the post i redirect to action.php which will hold the condition looking for the $post_type and the $id_post. So far i can echo both of them to test if the $_POST did his job but i'm still unable to delete in the custom post type ex : Bateaux

Comment: Are you actually doing this inside wordpress? does `action.php` include `get_header();` etc?

Comment: i solved the solution using a foreach if is array :) thks for your time.